# Cannot build LSTM layers in Keras

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I am trying to develop Keras LSTM code. I have input data which is represent audio features, it is like that.

> Training items [210969]
>
> Feature vector [40]
>
> Batch size [256]

data example

> [[-1.66514225 -0.44892017  0.24430933 ..., -0.96550658 -1.3456034 
>   -1.76591301]    [-1.79528513 -1.68822871  0.05168475 ..., -0.23602946 -0.26985581 -0.0951985 ]    [-0.09728797 -1.27619953 -1.48452426 ..., -1.11481965 -0.22158974 -1.10055417]]

In my Python code, I use Keras library. I try to build LSTM layers. I am using input_shape but i couldn't use well. I try to reshape my input data from 2 dimensional to 3 dimensional. you can see in fit function.

```
.........
elif classname == 'LSTM':
    layer_setup['config']['input_shape'] = (210969,40)
............
.......... 
model.fit(
            x=X_training.reshape(256,X_training.shape[0],X_training.shape[1]),
            y=Y_training.reshape(256,Y_training.shape[0],Y_training.shape[1]),
            batch_size=256,
            epochs=500,
            validation=validationdata,
            verbose=0,
            shuffle=true,
            callbacks=callbacks,
            class_weight=class_weight
        )
```

I got that error while i run code

> cannot reshape array of size 8438760 into shape (256,210969,40)

what should i do? Thanks

Comment: Did you reshape your validationdata?

Comment: yes. I am thinking that data can't be reshaped.

Comment: I don't think you have to reshape your data according to the batches, have you tried passing in the data without reshaping?

Comment: Yes. in that time I got error `Error when checking model input: expected lstm_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (210969, 40)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should reshape your data outside of the model creation because This way you try to create vector of `256 * 210969 * 40` from vector of size `8438760`. I think that the way for you to achieve what you want is something like this:

```
X = X_training.reshape((layer_setup['config']['input_shape'])) # now X.shape = 210969 * 40
y = Y_training.reshape((Y_training.shape[0],Y_training.shape[1]))
...
model.fit(
            x = X,
            y = y,
            batch_size=256,
            epochs=500,
            validation=validationdata,
            verbose=0,
            shuffle=true,
            callbacks=callbacks,
            class_weight=class_weight
        )
```